# post_per_page ignored in WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I have a custom post type named 'album' and I added two custom fields 'release_date' and 'release_date_us' with the [ACF plugin](http://advancedcustomfields.com/).

I'm trying to display the latest albums based in a widget area. The number of albums to show is set with my widget.

Here is the query I use in my widget :

```
<?php
    // WP_Query argument
    $arg = array(
      'post_type' => 'album',
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'release_date', // albums with release_date value less or equal than today
          'value' => date(Ymd),
          'compare' => '<=',
        ),
        array(
          'key' => 'release_date_us', // albums with release_date_us value less or equal than today
          'value' => date(Ymd),
          'compare' => '<=',
        ),
      ),
      'post_per_page' => $instance['number'] // number of albums to show. This is set to 1 in my widget
      'order' => 'DESC',
    );
    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
      }
    }
    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

My problem is that post_per_page parameter seems to be ignored.

The widget returns the three albums I created, not the last one as I expected.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** : I figured it out. I was using 'post_per_page' instead of 'posts_per_page'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter is called:

```
posts_per_page
```

so you are missing the plural »s« - more information about [`WP_Query` - Pagination Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) at the codex.